# Webpacker can't find application.js in D:/ROR/blog/public/packs/manifest.json in Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I am new in Rails 6.
I followed their document(https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) but I had some errors related to webpacker.
I made a route on routes file(config/routes.rb)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/articles", to: "articles#index"

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

And I created ArticlesController and its index action

```
bin/rails generate controller Articles index --skip-routes
```

And I run the server

```
bin/rails server
```

when I visit http://localhost:3000/articles, this error happend.

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Articles#index

Showing D:/ROR/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

Webpacker can't find application.js in D:/ROR/blog/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

[error with screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U20d4.png)

Comment: I suggest you switch to Linux, and start to study Rails from version 3.x

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I want to use rails 6.1. Are there any solutions on rails 6.1?

Comment: No, I haven't met this kind of problem. seems caused by webpack, which is useless in development environment. Rails 6 contains too many knowledge, Rails 3.x is much friendly to new bees.

Comment: :( Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue on mac.

Comment: @youthtech did you find any solution for this ?